# Uploading files (thumbnail size)

Tags: gnome, files, 22.04

Is it possible to change the thumbnail size when uploading files?
Currently running Ubuntu 22.04

Lets say for example, I want to attach something to my email, when I upload a file the thumbnails are tiny and I can barely see them.

I've tried nautilus, nemo, dolphin and thunar. None seem to really fix the problem.

I use Chrome as my browser, although I've tried firefox and the issue still exists.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCp2h.png)

Basically, is it possible to make the thumbnail size bigger while uploading files on a browser?